# How i can resize Div slideshow jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my slide show to my cover webpage 
width 100% height 500px 
But it's not like I want to do 
My img resolution "1200*575"
please help

CSS

```
#slide{
    width : 100%;
    height: 500px;   
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>IO-Hope</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bcat.bgswitcher.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleHome.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slide">
        </div>
        <script class="slidecon" type="text/javascript">
            var srcBgArray = ["./Img/Slide/1.jpg","./Img/Slide/2.jpg","./Img/Slide/3.jpg","./Img/Slide/4.jpg"];
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#slide').bcatBGSwitcher({
                    width :'100%' ,
                    height : 500 ,
                    urls: srcBgArray ,
                    effect : "fade", 
                    interval : 5000,
                    loop : true,
                    shuffle : true,
                    links: true,
                    prevnext: true
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the output from the Js? Are they output as background images?

Comment: iwat to do like this http://imgur.com/pEOSYsb
but this is code output http://i.imgur.com/nDuuddW.jpg

Comment: Thats an image, it's not code!

Comment: output JS just a image slideshow
//sorry thisis my first time for JS Orz""

Comment: so HTML output looks like `<img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg">`

Comment: We will need to see the HTML that the slideshow creates to give you a correct answer

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nLu2Xwn.jpg you mean this ??

Comment: set `#slide img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the slider is using the img tags and not using background images your options are slim.

I would suggest that if you want a perfect image then you will have to crop your images to fit the slider, if this isn't going to work for you then you can set a height on the slider and hide the overflow.

```
#slide {
  height: 525px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slide img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: it's no bother, Just without seeing the relevant code we are unable to supply a working fix for your problem. Glad it's working for you now.